# Why is move-constructor not called?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, rvalue, lvalue

I have the following piece of code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct T {
    int a;

    T() = default;

    T(T& other) {
        std::cout << "copy &\n";
    }

    T(T&& other) {
        std::cout << "move &&\n";
    }
};

void foo(T&& x) {
    T y(x); // why is copy ctor called??????
}

int main() {
    T x;
    foo(std::move(x));

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why copy constructor is preferred over move constructor even though `foo()` accepts rvalue-reference.

Comment: `x` is bound to an rvalue; but `x` itself is an lvalue. Oversimplified - when an object has a name it's an lvalue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`x` is an lvalue itself, even its type is rvalue-reference. [Value category](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) and type are two independent properties.

> Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression;

You need to use `std::move` to convert it to rvalue, just same as using `std::move` on `x` in `main()`.

```
void foo(T&& x)
{
    T y(std::move(x));
}
```

Comment: For a moment I was going to say `std::forward` would be more appropriate here, then realized the OP had named a `struct` `T` (concrete type, so `T&&` is actually a r-value reference), it wasn't the typical `template` `T` case (where `T&&` would be a universal reference). Sigh...

Comment: No, it would not, if T is a parameter of a struct template.

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed this in 1000 years. With all the quirks of C++ you can never get bored!